Как понять какой процесс занял процессорное время некоторое время назад на сервере Ubuntu 22.04?
У нас работает виртуальная машина и раз в сутки нагрузка на процессор становится почти 100% и приложение, которое крутится в виртуалке - вылетает.
При этом зайти на виртуалку невозможно ресурсов процессора не хватает, чтобы по ssh пустить. Помогает только перезагрузка.
При этом после перезагрузки все параметры в норме и посмотреть по htop, atop и т.д. виновника не получается. Есть какой то способ выловить процесс, который жрет ресурсы - по журналу или может какой сервис мониторинга несложный можно запустить?

Самое колхозное - запустить htop заранее и не закрывать, после вылета виртуалки выведенный htop'ом текст уже никуда не денется

То есть запустить htop > top.txt?

Вот файл после вылета как раз и не запишется, не надо так

Ну и вообще сразу два варианта вытекают непосредственно из вашего текста вопроса: «виртуальная машина» — значит у вас должен быть доступ к интерфейсу этой виртуальной машины, в том числе и к tty, никакой ssh вообще не нужен; «зайти на виртуалку невозможно ресурсов» — значит нужно просто зайти заранее

Кроме того, 100% нагрузка на процессор сама со себе не должна приводить к поломке ssh, то есть это скорее всего следствие нехватки памяти — добавьте память в виртуалку или хотя бы файл подкачки в надежде что зашевелится получше. Ах и да, через вышеупомянутый tty виртуальной машины должно быть возможно отправить Alt+SysRq+F для вызова oom killer'а, который прибьёт сожравший память процесс и оживит машину, позволив прочитать dmesg (но сперва нужно проверить, что sysrq в принципе включен)

Монитор показывает, что памяти в пике 80% используется. То есть до 100 не доходит. Хотя - возможно этого не хватает...

Если процесс занимал цпу, а потом резко перестал его занимать, то возможно его прибил OOM. Посмотрите dmesg
dmesg -T | egrep -i 'killed process'

Если процесс не убит, то посмотрите столбец time+ в htop. Время накапливается. Если процесс занимает много цпу - время накапливается быстрее.
Некоторые хостинги (там где виртуалки стоят меньше $2) шарят ядра. Запускают 30 виртуалок на 16 ядрах. тогда 100% загрузки цпу может происходить не на вашей виртуалке, а на соседской. Это можно приметить когда красная полоска в htop больше половины. Или обратите внимание на индикаторы  wa, hi, st в top
